# Array of objects

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using Mongo DB and Slim PHP in my app.

In mongo I have this array of objects

```
"dashboards" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52b96365481b9c02091d8698"),
            "title" : "Default title",
            "subtitle" : "Default subtitle",
            "metric_views" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52b9665f481b9c06091d8698"),
            "title" : "asdasdasd",
            "subtitle" : "asdasdasdas",
            "metric_views" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52b96666481b9c04091d8697"),
            "title" : "asdasdas",
            "subtitle" : "dasdasdas",
            "metric_views" : [ ]
        }
    ]
```

and for delete I wrote this function

```
function removeDashboard ($user,$dashboardMongoId) {
    foreach ($user['dashboards'] as $key => $dashboard) {
        if($user['dashboards'][$key]['_id']==$dashboardMongoId) {
            unset($user['dashboards'][$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $user['dashboards'];
}
```

after deleting one object my dashboards looks like this

```
"dashboards" : {
        "1" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52b9665f481b9c06091d8698"),
            "title" : "asdasdasd",
            "subtitle" : "asdasdasdas",
            "metric_views" : [ ]
        },
        "2" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52b96666481b9c04091d8697"),
            "title" : "asdasdas",
            "subtitle" : "dasdasdas",
            "metric_views" : [ ]
        }
    }
```

[] become {} and I get number for objects "1" , "2" , but the whole app is forking fine with this . Does anyone knows why is this happening and should I fix it or its ok to stay like this ?

Thanks !!

UPDATE :

Im creating default dashboard if there is no dashboards in Array maybe thats the problem , here is the code for that

```
$app->get('/getDashboards', function () {

    // Connect to database and select collection for loged in user
    $collection = selectMongoCollection('ctstats', 'users');
    $user       = findLoggedUser($collection);

    // Get all dashboards for user
    $data = $user['dashboards'];

    if(sizeof($user['dashboards']) == 0) {
        // Creating default dashboard
        $dashboard      = array(
                            "_id"          => new MongoId(),
                            "title"        =>"Default title", 
                            "subtitle"     =>"Default subtitle",
                            "metric_views" => array()
                        );

        // Saving dashboard to collection
        array_push($user['dashboards'],$dashboard);

        // Updating mongo with new data
        $collection->update($user,$user['dashboards']);
        $collection->save($user);
    }
    echo json_encode($user['dashboards']);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **MongoCollection::remove** PHP function of MongoDB client.
it will remove content from collection for given condition.

Comment: how to do that in this example ?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening here in your php function :

```
function removeDashboard ($user,$dashboardMongoId) {
    foreach ($user['dashboards'] as $key => $dashboard) {
        if($user['dashboards'][$key]['_id']==$dashboardMongoId) {
            unset($user['dashboards'][$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $user['dashboards'];
}
```

In php every kind of array is an array (in the php sense). This is not the case for mongodb/javascript in general, where an array is specifically a 0-based numerically indexed array, as opposed to hashes/documents/objects which are key-value arrays. When passing a data array through the mongodb driver, a conversion has to be made and I presume it basically checks the presence of a zero index to determine what mongodb storage type is best fitted.

In your php code you erase the value corresponding to the index 0, while *letting all other keys remain the same*. Since you don't seem to care about the keys, you could easily fix this with **array_value()** which will magically rebuild the array keys as a plain 0-based numerically indexed list:

```
function removeDashboard ($user,$dashboardMongoId) {
    foreach ($user['dashboards'] as $key => $dashboard) {
        if($user['dashboards'][$key]['_id']==$dashboardMongoId) {
            unset($user['dashboards'][$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return array_values($user['dashboards']);
}
```